# Sending JavaScript object as a string to

Tags: javascript, python, json, ajax, flask

I am using AJAX to POST a JSON string to Python Flask but the string doesn't seem to get passed to the flask app.

```
scoresaver.addEventListener('click', function(ev){
    if (scorestate==1) {
      var pdata = {'uname':uname, 'score':score.saved}
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/',
        data: JSON.stringify(pdata),   
        })
      score.saved=null;
      scorestate=0;
    }
});
```

On clicking a button the above code is supposed to "send" the JavaScript obj to Python Flask as a string. I have verified that JSON.stringify (pdata) produces the string I require.

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":

        print(request.get_json())

        return render_template("index.html")

    else:
        return render_template("index.html")
```

This is my code in my Flask application print (request.get_json() comes out to be None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add this key to your ajax call and try again:

```
contentType: "application/json",
```

The request's `get_json()` populates only if the content-type is set to be JSON.

Comment: This was was the exact cause of the problem.
Thanks for helping out